# Using webpack to create IE specific bundle for Angular2

Tags: angular, webpack

For an angular2 application, its required to include following scripts in index.html to make it work in Internet Explorer -

```
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

I am new to webpack and trying to understand whether I can pack all the 3 scripts in a single IE specific bundle.
What should my webpack.config.js look like? I tried below -

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
          'ie_vendor': './ie_vendor.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: "./package",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
...
};
```

ie_vendor.ts contains -

```
  import 'es6-shim'
  import 'system-polyfills'
  import 'shims_for_IE'
```

Obviously this fails with not able to find system-polyfills and shims_for_IE scripts.

Any suggestions?